# If you get a lot of upvotes in one day...?

Tags: support, reputation

So, I [answered a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42182/22599) last night, and it ended up getting a *lot* of upvotes today. I'm really flattered that so many people seemed to like it, but it seems that I hit the reputation cap pretty early on in the day. Will the reputation from the 12+ upvotes that didn't get counted as reputation-earners just be delayed till tomorrow? Will they just be completely ignored? I get why there would be a cap for a single day, but I also hate to think that honestly/well earned reputation wouldn't get awarded to somebody *at all*.

Comment: Reputation cap is SE's overall policy and in main meta, there is a good post explaining it in details  [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reach a day's reputation limit of 200, every additional reputation point you gain that day will be entirely lost in the empty void of nothingness forevermore. They will not be netted back on the next day (which might undermine the whole point of a reputation limit). There are some things, though, which are exempt from this limit and they're listed in the respective section of the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> [Bounty awards](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), [accepted answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), and [association bonuses](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

This is just something that you'll have to live with for now. There have been millions of posts asking for the reputation cap to be removed, increased, turned into a per-post limit, ... This is likely not going to happen in the near future, though, but the best place to find and further progress on those endeavours would probably be the [main meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com) (specifically the [`daily-reputation-limit` tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new/daily-reputation-limit?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&pageSize=50)). A good starting point might be [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/162011), whose answers explain the reasoning behind the reputation limit.